# How to keep (almost) the same splits of data in stratified sampling even when data is updated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, training-data, resampling

Generally it is suggested to sample a dataset such that test set and train set remain the same when running the code multiple times, for comparison but also to hide your algorithm the whole dataset. Since datasets change, and one might refetch it updated from the DB, a stable procedure is to use hash on the id or on a unique identifier. For example suppose one wants to divide the dataset between test and train with ratios respectively of 0.2 and 0.8. After calculating the hash of the id, since hashing should result in a uniform distribution, one might take the last byte and if it is smaller than `0.2*256` assign to the dataset, otherwise to the train set.

An example of this procedure is the following code:

```
import hashlib

def test_set_check(identifier, test_ratio, hash):
    return hash(np.int64(identifier)).digest()[-1] < 256 * test_ratio

def split_train_test_by_id(data, test_ratio, id_column, hash=hashlib.md5): 
    ids = data[id_column]
    in_test_set = ids.apply(lambda id_: test_set_check(id_, test_ratio, hash)) 
    return data.loc[~in_test_set], data.loc[in_test_set]
```

In this way, rows that in previous runs were assigned to the test-set, will always be assigned to the test-set even when new entries are added. The same holds for rows assigned to the trainset.

However, the same books state that it is important to keep original ratios of important categorical values between train and test sets. For example if women are 60% of global population, my train and test sets should reflect this. This is called **stratified sampling** and scikit-learn library has a function for that:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
#this loop is executed just once because n_splits=1?
for train_index, test_index in split.split(dataFrame, dataFrame["important_categorical_variable"]):
    train_set = dataFrame.loc[train_index]
    test_set  = dataFrame.loc[test_index]
```

If I run this multiple times it produces the same train and test sets because of the fixed random state. However, when the database is updated or changed this might not be the case and my train and test sets might look very different.

Is there a way to combine stratified sampling to preserve ratios with keeping (almost) the same train and test sets even when data are updated?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do a ```StratifiedShuffleSplit()``` on the new data before adding it respectively to your train and test datasets? On a side note, I suggest (though it might already be your case) using both a validation dataset and a testing dataset (where, in your case, the testing dataset wouldn't be ever changed before actually testing your model).

Comment: "important categorical values" - please note that sklearn only ensures original ratio for target variable/class, not categorical features (if I'm not mistaken...)

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince Can you explain better?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan I think you are wrong, the exact code in my question for stratified sampling is taken from a book: it is unlikely it is wrong.

Comment: What I mean is: you first create a train and test datasets using stratification and you keep them as such ; then, whenever you have new data, you wait until you have enough new data (if you only stratify on gender for instance, enough is probably around 30/50 new observations) to apply a ```StratifiedShuffleSplit()``` to the new dataset composed of these new observations, and you concatenate the first train and test datasets with respectively the new train and new test datasets that you have just created. That way, you do not change the original train and test apart from the data you add.

Comment: Now, of course, a better way to do that would be to add data recursively observation after observation (by keeping in memory what observations you have put in which dataset and choose where to put each new observation depending on what you have done in the past) because you wouldn't have to wait to have a set number of new observations, but I think that it could only require much more work to implement such thing.

Comment: Yes that's a possible way but it has the disadvantage that you have to save your train/test sets each time, or save new data on a separate table: anyway you have to keep a reference on data. The advantage of hashing is that it does not require you to do that.

Comment: again, I may be wrong, but it says "The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class." in the doc. Source code also doesn't seem to use X i.e. features anywhere. Can I please ask which book?

Comment: Sure: the book is `Hands n machine learning`. Don't know if you are wrong, I might have misinterpreted your comment

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Did you happen to come up with a good solution for this? I'm currently dealing with the exact same problem and would appreciate any tips :)

Comment: @DamjanKalšan No, unfortunately no and I stopped investigating but if you find a solution please let me know.